# How to show that the semigroup of OU-process?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

Following this question: [Prove that the Ornstein Uhlenbeck semigroup is given by $E(f(X_t))$ where $X_t$ is the Ornstein Uhlenbeck process](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2809413/prove-that-the-ornstein-uhlenbeck-semigroup-is-given-by-efx-t-where-x-t)

We define the OU-process as the solution to

$$dX_t=\sqrt 2 dB_t-X_t dt, \ X_0=x$$

and define the Markov semigroup as follows.
$$P_tf(x)=E(f(X_t))$$ for
$f\in \mathcal S$ (Schwartz space).

Question: how to show that the semigroup of OU-process is

$$P_t f(x)=E_{Y\sim \pi} f(e^{-t}x+\sqrt{1-e^{-2t}}Y)$$

where $\pi$ is the standard normal measure on $\Bbb R$.

---

We can solve that by Ito's fomula to $f(X_t)$ and I got:

$$X_t=e^{-t}x+\sqrt{2}\int_0^te^{-(t-s)}dB_s$$

Then
$$
E[X_t]=e^{-t}x
$$
and
$$
Var[X_t]=2(1-e^{-2t})
$$

Comment: "how to show that the semi group of the OU process is..." is that not what that linked post exactly does ? Have I misunderstood your question ? What step in the linked post is unclear ?

Comment: @KurtG. This step: Expressing $\mathbb{E}f(X_t)$ in terms of the density $p_t$ of $X_t$, $$\mathbb{E}f(X_t) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(y) p_t(y) \, dy,$$ it follows now easily that $\mathbb{E}f(X_t) = P_t f(x)$. I do not understand it.

Comment: From $X_t \sim N(e^{-t} x, 2(1-e^{-2t}))$ (which you also got) it follows that
$$
X_t=e^{-t} x+ \sqrt{2(1-e^{-2t})}\,\varepsilon
$$
whith some $\varepsilon\sim N(0,1)$. That's all I think.